# Does the standard allow `std::unique_ptr<void>`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, unique-ptr, std

Originated from [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308747/200711) Programmers topic. Does the C++14 standard ever allow the usage `std::unique_ptr<void>`? GCC 5.2 (C++14) produced the following error message with `std::unique_ptr<void>`:

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = void]':
/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:17:   required from 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = void; _Dp = std::default_delete<void>]'
prog.cc:4:25:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:72:2: error: static assertion failed: can't delete pointer to incomplete type
  static_assert(!is_void<_Tp>::value,
  ^
```

Obviously, this particular standard library implementation has specifically forbidden such usage. But what does the standard say about this? Language-lawyers would be apt here.

Comment: The deleter doesn't know how to delete a `void*`. Use a custom deleter.